# Real positive solution to specific system of equations

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

In the course of an optimization problem, I have encountered the following system of equations for $\alpha, \beta > 0$:
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 + a_2 + b_1 + b_2 &= \alpha + \beta\\
a_1b_1 + \frac{1}{4} a_2 b_2 &= \alpha \beta.
\end{align}
$$
Is there a general approach to tackle such a system and does this system have a real solution with $a_1, a_2 , b_1, b_2 > 0$?

Comment: If $\alpha = 0$ or $\beta = 0$ there is obviously no positive solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, naturally we assume $\alpha, \beta > 0$. I should change that in the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x + y = s$, $x y = t$ has solutions
$$ x = \frac{s - \sqrt{s^2 - 4 t}}{2},\ y = \frac{s + \sqrt{s^2 - 4 t}}{2} $$
which are positive if and only if $s^2 \ge 4 t$, and $s,t>0$.  Of course $(\alpha +\beta)^2 \ge 4 \alpha \beta$, with equality iff $\alpha = \beta$.

If $\alpha \ne \beta$, we can choose any $a_2$ and $b_2$ that are positive but small enough that $s > 0$, $t> 0$ and $s^2 > 4 t$
where $s = \alpha + \beta - a_2 - b_2$ and $t = \alpha \beta - a_2 b_2/4$.
Then we have positive solutions
$a_1 = (s - \sqrt{s^2 - 4 t})/2$, $b_1 = (s + \sqrt{s^2 - 4 t})/2$.

If $\alpha = \beta$, the system is not solvable with positive $a_1,a_2,b_1, b_2$, because squaring the first equation and subtracting $4$ times the second gives
$$ \left( a_{{1}}-b_{{1}} \right) ^{2}+2\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}+2\,a_{{1}}b_{{2
}}+{a_{{2}}}^{2}+2\,b_{{1}}a_{{2}}+a_{{2}}b_{{2}}+2\,b_{{1}}b_{{2}}+{b
_{{2}}}^{2}
=0$$

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you have set $s = \alpha + \beta - a_2 - b_2$ and $t = \alpha \beta - a_2 b_2 / 4$ from the beginning on?

Comment: And is the $\alpha = \beta$ case solvable if we have $1/n^2$ for some integer $n > 2$ as a factor in front of $a_2 b_2$ instead of $1/4$?

Comment: If $1/4$ is changed to $1/n^2$, in the $\alpha=\beta$ case squaring the first equation and subtracting $4$ times the second gives $$\left( a_{{1}}-b_{{1}} \right) ^{2}+{a_{{2}}}^{2}+ \left( 2-4/n^2 \right) a_{{2}}b_{{2}}+2\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}+2\,a_{{1}}b_{{2}}+{b_{{2}}
}^{2}+2\,b_{{1}}a_{{2}}+2\,b_{{1}}b_{{2}}=0
$$ which is impossible if $n \ge 2$ and all variables $> 0$.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help!

Comment: Going over the argument once more, I don't see how one could explicitly choose $a_2, b_2$ such that $s > 0, t>0$ and $s^2 > 4t$.

Comment: $s$, $t$, $s^2-4t$ are smooth functions of $a_2$ and $b_2$.  Get a bound on the gradient...